# syntax Error when changing field format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date field (var) holding date information in format of "mm-dd-yy" e.g 07-01-12. I need to change it to date format. I tried the following but doesn work. I get an Syntax error.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table-name` 
             SET `column-name` = STR_TO_DATE(`column-name`, '%m-%d-%y')")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the datatype of `column-name` is `DATETIME` or `DATE`, you cannot change its format. Leave it as is.

Just format the values during `SELECT` statements.

Or if you really want to have that kind of format, create a new column (*but don't delete the old one containing the dates*) which holds that kind of format. Of course the datatype should be `VARCHAR`.